# Passing an array or sequence to function in idl Java Corba

Tags: java, compiler-errors, corba

While trying to add an array or sequnce to function defined in idl file like

```
  // BackupDaemon.idl

  interface BackupDaemon;

  #ifndef BackupDaemon_idl
  #define BackupDaemon_idl

 typedef sequence<BackupDaemon> BackupDaemonList;

 #include "BackupExceptions.idl"


 interface BackupDaemon {



     boolean startBackup(in sequence<string> backupPathes ,in string backupDaemonMacAddress);

 };

 #endif
```

I got the following error :-

```
Expected one of `float' `double' `long' `short' `un
signed' `char' `wchar' `boolean' `octet' `any' `string' `wstring' `<identifier>'
 `::' `ValueBase'; encountered `sequence'.
     boolean startBackup(in sequence<string> backupPathes ,in string backupDaemo
nMacAddress);
```

So how can i pass an array or sequence to a function defined in idl file ?
Thanks in advance.
                            ^

Comment: is it java? re-tag your question.

Comment: I read the identifiers mapping and try that but every time i get error.

Comment: It 's related to CORBA , i modified tag . Thanks for this notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequences cannot be used directly in CORBA operations. You need to `typedef` them first:

```
typedef sequence<string> BackupPathesStrings;

interface BackupDaemon {
     boolean startBackup(in BackupPathesStrings backupPathes, in string backupDaemonMacAddress);
 };
```

See: [Sequences and Arrays](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/co-cjct5/index.html#h5)